intuition for neural network with a single hidden layer is a universal approximator?
Not a mathematician but I hope you can help me out, since it's a mathematical idea.
Verbal Description
Imagine an arbitrary function (continuous for the moment.) f and a neural net with a single hidden layer but infinite neurons in that layer (and use ReLU or max(0,x) as activation).
f could be approximated with small linear segments that approximate it locally.(see the little drawing.)
If the NN has infinite neurons in that single layer, then it can approximate each of the little line segments, and it would seem as one could do that for many (maybe all) continuous functions.
I find this intuition nice because even though one could use other functions, ReLU (or max(0,x)) makes a large part 0 besides the new weight (to be precise, affine transformations), which corrects the previous ones (the ones that aren't 0).
Hence this simple network can approximate many (maybe all) continuous functions. It's also quite clear why one would need infinite neurons for infinite functions, or infinitely good approximation.
Is this conceptually correct and maps to the universal approximation theorem used in neural networks?
Sketch
Below there is the visual idea/sketch (apologises, it looks messy.) described in the previous paragraphs.
For more clarity: f is the function to approximate (sin(x) in this case).
The purple lines are the segments that the network will output (continuous though.) and the text says that the max(0,x) will select the appropriate piece, and keep all other off when w_i x_i + b_i < 0 and so on.
The interesting bit is that the pieces correct each other, for example: relu(w_1 x_1) + relu(w_2 x_1) +... can either not interfere with each other, or add up the slopes (making a correction in the previous segment, hence represents any function.)

Wikipedia description

Universal approximation theorems are limit theorems: They simply state that for any
f and a criteria of closeness ϵ > 0, if there are enough neurons in a neural network, then there exists a neural network with that many neurons that does approximate
f to within ϵ. There is no guarantee that any finite size, say, 10000 neurons, is enough.

The whole description is much more complex, you can find it here.

I think you might find this account of the universal approximation property to be helpful
